# Hypernym for class an struct in C++

Tags: c++

What is a good hypernym for the terms *class* and *struct* in C++?

I have a datastructure in which I want to insert names of classes and structs, so I want to give it a meaningful name. I do not like `StructAndClassList` very much. Maybe *record* is a common hypernym ?

Comment: "User-defined non-union type."

Comment: @Oliver Charlesworth Types also include standard types like integers etc...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's no separate notion of struct in C++. `struct` is a keyword. Entities introduced by this keyword, and also by `class` and `union` keywords, are called *classes*.

The standard uses the term "non-union class" to distinguish classes that are not unions.

Answer (score 0):

`Type` Both are types. Consider just using what your datastructure does or looks like as a name e.g. `Tree`.